# Crazy problems with HTML and stylesheets: stuff is showing up that I didn't even write

Tags: css, html, stylesheet

This problem is incredibly hard to describe.  I feel like I've entered the twilight zone.  However, I'm new to HTML and CSS, and there's a great chance I'm doing something completely wrong.

I have multiple files in a folder, amongst them are: style.css, homePage.html, and addPerson.php

I'm intending style.css to be an external style sheet to handle both pages.  I wrote addPerson.php first and had no problems getting it to work with the external stylesheet.  However, once I added the homePage.html file (which is linked to on the addPerson.php webpage), I'm having all sorts of crazy problems.  On the left of the page of my addPerson.php page, there is an unordered list of links, stuck on the left using "float".  In my homePage.html file, I want to have this same exact list.  Thus, I copied and pasted the code into that file.  Here's what that code looks like:

```
<body>
    <div class="Links">
    <p>
    Add new content:
    <ul>
    <li><a href="addComments.php">Add comments to movies</a></li>
    <li><a href="addMovieInfo.php">Add movie information</a></li>
    </ul>
    Browse content:
    <ul>
    <li><a href="showActorInfo.php">Actors</a></li>
    <li><a href="showMovieInfo.php">Movies</a></li>
    </ul>
    Search:
    <ul>
    <li><a href="searchActorsOrMovies.php">Search</a></li>
    </ul>
    </p>
    </div>
```

Here's what the "Links" class, from style.css looks like that was referenced:

```
.Links
{
float: left;
background-color:#E6E6E6;
height: 522px;
}
```

That piece of code makes it so that there's a list of links with a grey background that runs down the left side of the page.  It works just fine in addPerson.php.  Here's a screenshot of that file: http://i1126.photobucket.com/albums/l610/cpatton1027/Screenshot2011-04-25at104256PM.png?t=1303796942

However, when I copy and paste that piece of code into homePage.html, I find that it doesn't work.  Rather, the class reference doesn't do a thing.  It just shows up as an unordered list of links, without the grey background or anything.  Thus, homePage.html looks like this: http://i1126.photobucket.com/albums/l610/cpatton1027/Screenshot2011-04-25at104311PM.png?t=1303796993

Thinking that was a little weird, I ran a few tests on homePage.html.  I cut down the code to just this:

```
<body>
    <div class="Links">
    <p>
    Add new content:
    <ul>
    <li><a href="addComments.php">Add comments to movies</a></li>
    <li><a href="addMovieInfo.php">Add movie information</a></li>
    </ul>
    </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

However, I find that when doing this, things got very strange!  Here's a picture: http://i1126.photobucket.com/albums/l610/cpatton1027/Screenshot2011-04-25at104341PM.png?t=1303797030

That makes no sense at all to me.

I then cut the code down even further, to:

```
<body>
    <div class="Links">
    <p>
    Add new content:
    <ul>
    <li><a href="addComments.php">Add comments to movies</a></li>
    </ul>
    </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Now with this change, it suddenly looked correct.  The grey background was there, and the rest of the text was not.  Here is what that looked like: http://i1126.photobucket.com/albums/l610/cpatton1027/Screenshot2011-04-25at105119PM.png?t=1303797106

What the heck is going on?  Why is the Links class working perfectly in my initial file but horribly in this new file I'm creating?  (note: there are a bunch of other weird things that has happened in trying to figure this out, but since I've already written a novel I decided to just slim it to this problem).

Comment: This is unlikely to be your problem, but just so you know, `<p>` elements cannot contain `<ul>` elements. The browser will get confused, and auto-close the `<p>` tag when it sees the `<ul>` starting, then find a mismatched closing `</p>` after the `</ul>` and not know what that's all about.

Comment: mu is too short: do you mean the actual website?  I could provide some screenshots, but the website isn't actually on the internet (it's just being locally hosted.

Comment: @Domenic: Why isn't it possible for a <p> element to contain a <ul> element?

Comment: @the_drow — because paragraphs can only hold inline content and lists are block elements.

Comment: @DavidDorward: So what is the valid markup to specify a paragraph with a list inside it?

Comment: I edited it so that the lists were not inside the paragraph elements, but this did not solve the problem.  However, thank you for the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if this was a caching problem? Browsers tend to cache pages rather than going back to the server to fetch them...if you're updating a page frequently, remember to press Ctrl + F5 to clear the cache and completely re-fetch the page, or else you might think your changes aren't getting saved.

If you put the text back in, does homePage.html revert to the non-working version?

EDIT: Also, of course, it might be a problem with the server not having the right version of the code you are expecting it to have. If you view the source and see that it doesn't have the HTML you expect it to have, then you'll need to make sure you are making a request to the right place, and that that place has the right code. This includes HTML, PHP, and CSS pages.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I am certain this is not a caching problem.  I've checked this already and am constantly reloading the page.  Further, if I just delete the whole html file and then open up the webpage, I find that it is blank.  Even upon restarting my computer these weird problems still persist.  After removing the text (and thus it has one link with a grey background correctly), and then reinserting it back in, the problems persist.

Comment: Strange indeed...would it be possible to get a link to see the pages live somewhere? Also, as a debugging tip, make sure that you check the page source of the page you are testing to make sure it is getting the HTML you are expecting it to get. A tool like Firebug on Firefox might also be of help, or Inspector in Chrome.

Comment: I used Firebug and found that it is NOT getting the code I'm expecting it to get.  Please take a look at my initial post: I edited it to include pictures of everything.

Comment: I saw the pictures, and they indeed reflect what you are describing. Since we can't see the code live, would it be possible to get a pastebin of homePage.html and the style.css file for us to look at and render ourselves?

Comment: For what it's worth, I just created the following HTML/CSS: http://pastebin.com/Ws9azQGp and it worked perfectly...

Comment: Seems likely to be some kind of deployment problem. I would be very surprised if the code on the server was the same as the code you are editing in your IDE.

Comment: I just tried out your pastebin code and it is working exactly as one should expect it to work. If it's not a problem with the pages getting cached, then perhaps Domenic is right and the code is not getting on the server you are pulling from in the way you think. Make sure that the code is on the right server in the right place, and that the URL you are requesting is correct. The code you have should be working, but for whatever reason, the server is not giving you the pages you think it should be giving you.

Comment: Hey Ben, I too find that when I only have the two files it works fine.  Something about the php file usage is just messing it up I guess..

Comment: ok now after moving the files out and back in, I find that the code is working.  However, if I try to modify homePage.html, like adding <p>There is text here </p> after all the links, I find that the text is not there.  How can I verify that the code is on the right server in the right place?  Seems like some sort of server problem here...but how can I diagnose it? How could a server error explain this: http://i1126.photobucket.com/albums/l610/cpatton1027/Screenshot2011-04-25at104341PM.png?t=1303797030

Comment: I'm assuming you are uploading your files to the server via FTP or SFTP or SCP or something similar. One thing you can do is to add some extra text to the page that's obvious -- changing a link name, adding an HTML comment, or whatever -- and when you go to pull the page after re-uploading it, press Ctrl + U after the page is loaded (view source) to make sure it has exactly the right HTML that you expect. If not, make sure you do a Ctrl + F5 to make sure it's not cached. If the change is still not appearing, either the file didn't get uploaded, or put in the right place, or the URL is wrong.

Comment: Also make sure that your style.css file is correct by navigating to it directly (http://192.168.56.20/~cs143/proj1C/style.css should be it, I think)

Comment: I have tried adding extra obvious text to the page, such as <p>There is text here </p> but am finding that this text isn't showing up.  Maybe it's a server problem, but how would I fix this? The link is right...it's being uploaded to the server in the same way as always. Why would certain edits show up and not others?  I'm doing hard refreshes to verify this is not a cache problem.

Comment: You may want to talk to the person administrating the server. It could be any number of reasons. For example, it could be that the server you are pulling from is actually a load-balancer for a cluster of servers, and changes have to propagate throughout the cluster before they appear consistently. (That probably isn't likely, but it's certainly possible.) If you are sure that the changes you make are not appearing in the page source, and the page is not cached, then all I can suggest is that you talk to the person who manages the server to make sure you are using it correctly.

Comment: Also, you could install a local web server on your own computer (such as XAMPP) and test there on localhost where things are more consistent.

Comment: Thanks for all the advice.  I don't really feel like workshopping the server (this is for a school project, and we're using the school's server so this would be tough to do).  However, I've switched to internal stylesheets and have found this seemed to solved the problem.  I guess the server just couldn't really handle external stylesheets?  Very odd.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to set your doctype.